# How to fill blank space with border or add empty rows in table

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to fill blank space in jasper report or empty rows in table
my report is

[image: Jasper report file]

I have tried

```
<box>
    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
</box>
```

to add horizontal line to detail band but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `background` band, to draw the fixed lines you need.

```
<background>
    <band height="800">
        ... add lines you like to be in page background
    </band>
</background>
```

As a note the `columnFooter` can be moved up under the table using the attribute `isFloatColumnFooter="true"` on the `jasperReport` tag