# How to set the frame of row to continue until it fits the detail band height?

Tags: jasper-reports

Please kindly advise the below image. Now I have a report. If the report has fetched the data in the database.  I want the frame of row  to continue until it fits the detail band height . Can I do that and how?

**Data in table have 3 rows (example)**

Now result :

```
    --------------------------------
    |1   | xxxxxxx |          400.0|
    --------------------------------
    |2   | xxxxxxx |          500.0|        <- detail band
    --------------------------------
    |3   | xxxxxxx |          100.0|
    --------------------------------

                                   <--  Blank  

         ---------------------------
         |    TOTAL |        1000.0|        <- Summary band
         ---------------------------
```

[Now result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0WdQ.png)

The result what I want:

```
    --------------------------------
    |1   | xxxxxxx |          400.0|
    --------------------------------
    |2   | xxxxxxx |          500.0|
    --------------------------------
    |3   | xxxxxxx |          100.0|
    --------------------------------
    |    |         |               |
    --------------------------------
    |    |         |               |
    --------------------------------
    |    |         |               |
    --------------------------------
         |    TOTAL|         1000.0|        
         ---------------------------
```

[The result what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pddaZ.png)

**XML Script :** https://www.mediafire.com/file/rdle3kdigryh5sj/testpage.txt

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: This is also related [Can JRXML extend data source before using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36859225/5292302) but I think the background band will do the trick for you as long as you don't use stretchWithOverflow (draw the lines in background band and remove lines from detail band)

Comment: This link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626453/how-to-fill-blank-space-with-border-or-add-empty-rows-in-table can solved it!! THANK YOU.

Comment: Your welcome and thanks for accepting duplicate, it helps to improve SO for future users